# Modifying a recipe, changing it from 8 to 10 servings.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A recipe that makes 8 servings calls for 3/5 cup flour. Jeff modifies the recipe so that it can serve 10.

How many cups of flour does he need?

Comment: Please tell us what you've tried so far and where your problems are. This site is meant to help you with maths, not solve your homework.

Comment: It's September again.

Answer (score 1):

Try to find the missing length.

**Hint**: what are the horizontal and vertical dimensions of the green triangle.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The recipe is $\frac{10}{8}$ as large, so you need $\frac{10}{8}$ as much of each ingredient. For flour, this is 
\begin{align}
\frac{10}{8}\cdot \frac{3}{5} &=\frac{10\cdot 3}{8\cdot 5}\\
&= \frac{30}{40} \\
&= \frac{3}{4} 
\end{align}
cups.